# Framework7 redirect to new page when login is successful with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I'm trying to create a new project in Framework7 with a login and registration. My login and registration work however when you login successfully and try and navigate to the main menu page it loses the style sheet? I'm not sure if it's because with Framework7 you only link the style sheet in the index.html page?
This is my javascript;

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //bind enter key to click button
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      if ($('#loginform').is(":visible")) {
        $("#loginbutton").click();
      } else if ($('#signupform').is(":visible")) {
        $("#signupbutton").click();
      }
    }
  });

  $('#signup').click(function() {
    $('#loginform').slideUp();
    $('#signupform').slideDown();
    $('#myalert').slideUp();
    $('#signform')[0].reset();
  });

  $('#login').click(function() {
    $('#loginform').slideDown();
    $('#signupform').slideUp();
    $('#myalert').slideUp();
    $('#logform')[0].reset();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#signupbutton', function() {
    if ($('#susername').val() != '' && $('#spassword').val() != '' && $('#semail').val() != '' && $('#sgender').val() != '' && $('#sweight').val() != '' && $('#sheight').val() != '') {
      $('#signtext').text('Signing up...');
      $('#myalert').slideUp();
      var signform = $('#signform').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://cs1.ucc.ie/~lmm12/pjt/signup2.php',
        data: signform,
        success: function(data) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myalert').slideDown();
            $('#alerttext').html(data);
            $('#signtext').text('Completed');
            $('#signform')[0].reset();

          }, 4000);
          window.location = "index.html";

        }
      });
    } else {
      alert('Please input all fields to Sign Up');
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#loginbutton', function() {
    if ($('#username').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '') {
      $('#logtext').text('Logging in...');
      $('#myalert').slideUp();
      var logform = $('#logform').serialize();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://cs1.ucc.ie/~lmm12/pjt/login2.php',
          data: logform,
          success: function(data) {
            if (data == '') {
              $('#myalert').slideDown();
              $('#alerttext').text('Login Successful. User Verified!');
              $('#logtext').text('Login');
              $('#logform')[0].reset();
              setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = "menu.html";

              }, 2000);

            } else {
              $('#myalert').slideDown();
              $('#alerttext').html(data);
              $('#logtext').text('Login');
              $('#logform')[0].reset();
            }
          }
        });
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      alert('Please input both fields to Login');
    }
  });
});
```

I've been using window.location, however the style sheet disappears?

Comment: are you sure you linked the stylesheet to the index.html file? You did not show us that

Comment: stylesheets should not be loaded through javascript in good practise. The should be laoded straight in html files